# How to stop textarea adding empty values in database?

Tags: jquery

I use similar post like facebook but i have issues with empty values. I can post only picture or text, and both also. But when I pres the button its adding empty value and want to stop that.Below I have the id of the form and I appreciate your help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var formid = $('#main_post_form').val().
        var textarea = $('#text').val();
        var input = $('#myfile').val();
        var postbutton = $('#button');

    });
```

Comment: We need more content, how do you add data to database? Which language? Show your code, here you are just assigning values. This question is too broad

Comment: function postThis($message)
     {
        $this->id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $post = new Post();
        $post->userid = $this->id;
        $post->message = $message;
        $post->posttime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $id = $post->publish();
         if(isset($_FILES['file_img']) && $_FILES['file_img']['size'] > 0)
        {
            $thisfoto = new Photo();
            $thisfoto->postid = $id;
            $thisfoto->publish();
        }

     }  $user = new User();
    if(isset($_POST['add_post'])){
        $user->postThis($_POST['saysomething']);
   }

Comment: In the question itself...

Comment: What, *exactly*, is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose various options, but it's easy to use a JavaScript `trim()` method, if you want to remove blank space at the beginning and in the end.

Besides, you can also format the text before persist it into a database.

The most of server-side languages has a `trim()` method equivalent.

Comment: maybe mention: clientside is a bad idea, since client side code can be editted by the end-user always do database validation at the end on server side

Comment: Notice that I haven't mentioned ONLY client-side. It's safer using various approach. Client-side>Server-side>Database validation, as you mentioned.
But you're right, only client-side isn't a good idea.

Comment: No honestly, I just meant can you put that in as a note so that people who don't know will know that javascript isn't the end all be all on this one

Comment: How in the world does this answer the OP's question? We don't know what the question even is, just that the OP is getting blank values. this has nothing to do with validation or trimming or anything like that at this point.